# Get the peak memory usage of a job after it is completed using jobid in linux

Tags: linux, unix

linux/unix command to know the peak and average memory usage of job after it is completed form the jobid

commands like ps,top,htop, grep VmPeak only works for processes

Comment: You can't. Linux doesn't keep that kind of data around after a process has terminated. Your best chance would be to execute your program under e.g. the control of valgrind.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, this information is lost once the process exits -- Linux does not keep that information around (also the PID will eventually be recycled).

If you can arrange to run the process inside a wrapper, you can easily get the info from GNU `time` (not to be confused with the shell built-in), which is probably already installed on your system.

For example:

```bash
$ /usr/bin/time --verbose gcc -E /usr/include/unistd.h > /dev/null    
        Command being timed: "gcc -E /usr/include/unistd.h"
        User time (seconds): 0.01
        System time (seconds): 0.00
        Percent of CPU this job got: 71%
        Elapsed (wall clock) time (h:mm:ss or m:ss): 0:00.02
        Average shared text size (kbytes): 0
        Average unshared data size (kbytes): 0
        Average stack size (kbytes): 0
        Average total size (kbytes): 0
        Maximum resident set size (kbytes): 8664
        Average resident set size (kbytes): 0
        Major (requiring I/O) page faults: 0
        Minor (reclaiming a frame) page faults: 2586
        Voluntary context switches: 38
        Involuntary context switches: 3
        Swaps: 0
        File system inputs: 0
        File system outputs: 0
        Socket messages sent: 0
        Socket messages received: 0
        Signals delivered: 0
        Page size (bytes): 4096
        Exit status: 0
```